# Obtain the t -statistic for the test that the slopes of the regressions are zero

Tags: r, statistics, t-test

I have data on birth proportion every year for four different countries.
I have fitted this data with four simple regression lines using the code:-

```
mbirthprop <- read.csv("ex0724.csv")
attach(mbirthprop)
summary(lm(Denmark~Year))
summary(lm(Netherlands~Year))
summary(lm(Canada~Year))
summary(lm(USA~Year))
```

The goal is to calculate the t-statistic for the test that the slopes of the regressions are zero using R.
How do I do that?
Also how to print out/display the graphs with the regression line?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Also each post should ask just one question at a time.

Comment: Alright ! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
sfit <- summary(fit)
sfit$coefficients[,c("t value")]

(Intercept)         cyl 
      18.27       -8.92
```